# Close Java Frame by clicking X button

Tags: java, awt

Here is a piece of code that I wrote but the close button on the top of the application doesn't work please help

Code:

```html
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class App extends Frame implements MouseMotionListener {
 App() {
  addMouseMotionListener(this);
  setSize(200, 200);
  setVisible(true);
 }

 public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
  Graphics g = getGraphics();
  g.setColor(Color.RED);
  g.fillRect(e.getX(),  e.getY(),10, 10);
 }

 public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
 }

 public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
  App a = new App();
 }

}
```

Image:

[image: Application Screenshot The close button is not working]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add Listener and call dispose while initializing your applet.

```
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        dispose();
    }
});
```

You need to add above line of code inside the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with that little code:

```
this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

});
```

You have to insert it in "App()". It will close the program "System.exit(0);"
when you press the close button.

Answer (score 0):

im not using AWT often but heres my Solution :)

```
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){
    System.exit(0);
    }
});
```

Add a new WindowAdapter to your App Constructor and call system.exit(0) on the Window Close Event

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WindowContants](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html) on [JFrame#setDefaultCloseOperation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation-int-) to achieve the desired action. This allows you to dispose the frame, entirely terminate the application and a few more with a single line in the constructor:

```
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowContants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

will dispose the frame containing the app. This is sufficient to terminate the program you presented.

This approach doesn't allow handling any events though, but simply closes the frame.